# Fetch data combining SOAP and REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage, wsproxy, content-assets

I am trying to fetch all Triggered sends in our account and associated emails (email name) used in triggered send but unable to do so.

Issue being triggeredsendDefinition is fetched thru SOAP or WSProxy and Email data is fetched thru REST api asset object.

How to combine these two objects in script activity or cloudpage

Answer (score 2):

I probably wouldn't mix the two, I would instead use the REST MessageDefinition Endpoint to get the `message.content.id` and then use that to grab the HTML via the REST Asset endpoint.

Something like this:

```
GET /messaging/v1/messageSends
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Which will return something like:

```json
{
    "count": 49,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/v1/messageSends"
        }
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "key": "trigger",
            "partnerKey": "",
            "name": "trigger",
            "description": "trigger",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-27T07:08:00",
            "modifiedDate": "2021-03-02T08:32:00",
            "triggeredSendType": 0,
            "triggeredSendStatus": 1,
            "isPlatformObject": false,
            "categoryId": 54321,
            "message": {
                "content": {
                    "id": 12345,
                    "contentId": 0
                },
                "options": {
                    "isMultipart": false,
                    "isLinkTrackingOn": false
                }
            },
            "subject": {
                "subject": "asdf",
                "dynamicEmailSubject": "asdf"
            },
            "from": {
                "address": "test@test.com",
                "name": "Training"
            },
            "sendClassification": {
                "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
                "customerKey": "Default Transactional"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the part we want to grab from:

```json
            "message": {
                "content": {
                    "id": 12345,
                    "contentId": 0
                }
```

In this we get the 'Email ID' of the asset, which is also known as the 'Legacy ID'.

So, then using that information, we make a call to the Asset Endpoint with a Filter, like so:

```
GET /asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=data.email.legacy.legacyId%20eq%20'12345' HTTP/1.1
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
```

Where the filter is pushing the number we gathered in the previous API call `12345` and putting it as the value we are searching for in the filter.
`$filter=data.email.legacy.legacyId%20eq%20'12345'`

This will return a full asset response payload. From there you can grab whatever information you need.

Also, if you desperately need to utilize SOAP for this, I would utilized WSProxy for the SOAP (returns as a JSON) that can easily be manipulated in SSJS and then using **[Script.Util.HttpRequest](https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/)** you can make your REST call.

Example WSProxy call for TriggeredSendDefinition:

```js
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var cols = ["CustomerKey", "Email.ID"];
var filter = {
      Property: "CustomerKey",
      SimpleOperator: "Equals",
      Value: "myCustKey"
};
var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendDefinition", cols, filter);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gotonington, I did not see the route for Triggered send using REST. This was really helpful.

I mostly use endpoints provided > https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm in this doc
Are there other endpoints?